# I can't deploy my Python-Django app on Heroku

Tags: heroku

When I'm trying to deploy my Python project using `git push heroku master`
on terminal, I got an error

> remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository 'https://github.com/heroku/myproject.git/' not found.

I tried to fix this problem by giving `heroku git:remote -a falling-wind-1624` command. But I can't solve this problem.

Comment: Did you execute `heroku create` ? Can you post your `.git/config` file here?

Comment: Yes I used heroku create commant and also config.